# User Warning: The following kwargs were not used by contour: 'label', 'color'

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, valueerror

Im trying to create a comparison plot using Seaborn's PairGrid function on my dataset.  My data set has 6 columns that I am trying to plot using the scatter() function in my .map_upper segment of the PairGrid function I'm applying to the entire dataframe. Here is a quick peak at my dataframe object; the 'year' object is set as the dataframe's index

Here are the data types of my dataframe comp_pct_chg_df:

year             object
Amsterdam       float64
Barcelona       float64
Kingston        float64
Milan           float64
Philadelphia    float64
Global          float64
dtype: object

Here is my erroneous code below:

```
# Creating a comparison plot (.PairGrid()) of all my cities' and global data's average percent change in temperature

# Set up my figure by naming it 'pct_chg_yrly_fig', then call PairGrid on the DataFrame
pct_chg_yrly_fig = sns.PairGrid(comp_pct_chg_df.dropna())

# Using map_upper we can specify what the upper triangle will look like.
pct_chg_yrly_fig.map_upper(plt.scatter,color='purple')

# We can also define the lower triangle in the figure, including the plot type (KDE) or the color map (BluePurple)
pct_chg_yrly_fig.map_lower(sns.kdeplot,cmap='cool_d')

# Finally we'll define the diagonal as a series of histogram plots of the yearly average percent change in temperature
pct_chg_yrly_fig.map_diag(plt.hist,histtype='step',linewidth=3,bins=30)

# Adding a legend
pct_chg_yrly_fig.add_legend()
```

Some of the visualizations do plot out, like the .map_lower() function I used, which turned out great. I'd like to plot each city however, in a different color for my scatter plot used in the .map_upper() function I've used. Right now its monochromatic, and hard to tell which data points belong to which city. And lastly, my .map_diag() doesn't plot at all. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I've assessed the ValueError msg I received (which is   below) and tried manipulating dozens of **kwargs, label and color specifically, to no avail. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Here is the ValueError msg I'm receiving: 

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-3fcf1b69d4ef> in <module>()
     11 
     12 # Finally we'll define the diagonal as a series of histogram plots of the yearly average percent change in temperature
---> 13 pct_chg_yrly_fig.map_diag(plt.hist,histtype='step',linewidth=3,bins=30)
     14 
     15 # Adding a legend

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in map_diag(self, func, **kwargs)
   1361 
   1362                 if "histtype" in kwargs:
-> 1363                     func(vals, color=color, **kwargs)
   1364                 else:
   1365                     func(vals, color=color, histtype="barstacked", **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in hist(x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, normed, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3023                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,
   3024                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,
-> 3025                       stacked=stacked, normed=normed, data=data, **kwargs)
   3026     finally:
   3027         ax._hold = washold

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1715                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1716                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1717             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1718         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1719         if pre_doc is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in hist(***failed resolving arguments***)
   6137             color = mcolors.to_rgba_array(color)
   6138             if len(color) != nx:
-> 6139                 raise ValueError("color kwarg must have one color per dataset")
   6140 
   6141         # If bins are not specified either explicitly or via range,

ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per dataset
```

I also noticed that my index, the year object, is plotting out in the upper left corner of my PairGrid. It looks like a bunch of vertical lines plotted next to one another.  Not sure why it’s plotting but could it be because the values ( years 1743 - 2015) end in ‘.0’? I noticed this when I put the data frame together (and I don’t know how to drop it... Python newb here) so I changed the year column’s data type from float64 to string and set it as my index. I thought doing this would make my index ‘unworkable’ meaning even though the values are numbers, the data type is set to string so no calculations could be done on them? Am I missing something here?

Comment: You would provide a [mcve] of the issue, such that people are able to reproduce it.